# ggplot2 + scatterplot + geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Do you know how to get the curved effect Jake Kaupp achieves on his plot?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be something along the lines of:

```r
ggplot(full_data, aes(y = total_consumption_lbs, x = milk_production_lbs)) +
  geom_xspline2(aes(s_open = TRUE, s_shape = 0.5))
```

Where `geom_xspline2()` comes from `library(ggalt)`

But don't ask me, here is his source code:

https://github.com/jkaupp/tidytuesdays/blob/master/2019/week5/R/analysis.R

Comment: I tried to locate Jake Kaupp's code unsuccessfully. Your help has been very beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't look quite as nice as your example, but it's a start, and some fiddling may get you the rest of the way.

First, some data to work with:

```
x <- seq(1:20)
y <- jitter(x,amount=1.5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

The approach using `ggplot2` is to draw a `geom_smooth` with very small span (small enough to cause lots of errors, as you'll see), and then plot points with white borders over the top of that.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="black", span=0.15) +
  geom_point(fill="black", colour="white", shape=21, size=2.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**The downsides:** As I noted above, you'll see many errors about singularities in the loess fit, because the span is so small. Second, you'll note that not all of the points are centred on the line, which makes sense since you are using a loess fit for the line. Lastly, there doesn't appear to be a way to change the width of the line around the points, so you end up with quite a thin white border.

Comment: My interest lies in building a connected scatterplot like the one Jake Kaupp proposes. In the answer above this possibility is offered. In any case, I'm very grateful for your guidance, and options I didn't know about for other scatterplots.